# Inserting values in postgres but they are interpreted as column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to insert some data in my postgres databae like this:

```
  def insert_row(conn, row)
    attendee = map_row_to_struct(row)

    conn.execute(
      <<-SQL
        INSERT INTO tmp_attendee_import (email, first_name, last_name)
        VALUES("#{attendee.email}", "#{attendee.first_name}", "#{attendee.last_name}");
      SQL
    )
  end
```

The SQL is evaluated wonderfully as:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_attendee_import (email, first_name, last_name)
VALUES("myemail@yahoo.com", "Gigel", "Ion");
```

Yet I get this error:

```
Failure/Error:
               conn.execute(
                 <<-SQL
                   INSERT INTO tmp_attendee_import (email, first_name, last_name)
                   VALUES("#{attendee.email}", "#{attendee.first_name}", "#{attendee.last_name}");
                 SQL
               )

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "myemail@yahoo.com" does not exist
       LINE 2:             VALUES("myemail@yahoo.com", "Gigel", "Ion");
                                  ^
       :             INSERT INTO tmp_attendee_import (email, first_name, last_name)
                   VALUES("myemail@yahoo.com", "Gigel", "Ion");
```

Anyone has any clue ?

Comment: are you working on ruby on rails ?

Comment: yes 4.2 is the current used veersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS)

> A string constant in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters
>   bounded by single quotes ('), for example 'This is a string'. To
>   include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two
>   adjacent single quotes, e.g., 'Dianne''s horse'. **Note that this is not
>   the same as a double-quote character (")**.
>
> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
>   quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of
>   characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an
>   identifier, never a key word. So "select" could be used to refer to a
>   column or table named "select", whereas an unquoted select would be
>   taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when
>   used where a table or column name is expected.

**TL;DR: Single quotes for string constants, double quotes for table/column names.**

BTW, the way you're choosing for inserting records is vulnerable to [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I will use the activerecord sanitizer before, thank you for the tip! Yep just figured it out 30 seconds ago this is right